# YQL Open Data Table for Wikipedia

Tags: parsing, wikipedia, yql

Has anyone written a YQL open data table for accessing Wikipedia? I've had a hunt around the internet and found mention of people using YQL for extracting various bits of information from Wikipedia pages such as microformats, links or content but I haven't been able to find an open data table that ties it all together.

Comment: There certainly isn't one in the main data table repository. Are you looking for anything specific or literally entire (read,write?) access to Wikipedia through YQL?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of community tables - mediawikiapi.* See if it helps.
-b-